# 1 chroot sftp user that is able to traverse all other chroot sftp users files/folders

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, sftp, chroot-jail

I have a chroot environment that I have setup on CentOS 6. We have users for all of our trading partners and I would like to create an internal user for another department that can sftp in and only see all the folders/sub-folders/files of all the other users but not have access to the system root. Is this possible? I have tried bind mounting the client incoming and outgoing folders to the internal user and am not able to see any files or sub folders of the bind mounts. Same for Symbolic Links (which show up as shortcut files when viewed in filezilla)